# Swift converting Byte Array into String

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode

I can't convert this below byte array into String in swift.

```
let chars: [UInt8] =  [255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0]

let datastring = NSString(data: chars, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

But in android it just works fine I don't know whats wrong in swift.

Comment: Sorry its typo mistake.. now I updated the question

Comment: Do you get any errors? Is that really UTF-8?

Comment: Which version of Swift are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`[UInt8]` is not `NSData`, so you can't use the `NSString(data...` initializer

You might use

```
let chars: [UInt8] =  [255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0]
let count = chars.count / sizeof(UInt8)
let datastring = NSString(bytes: chars, length: count, encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding)
```

In Swift 3 things have become much easier as a native `String` can be initialized with a sequence of bytes.

```
let datastring = String(bytes: chars, encoding: .utf8)
```

However the example is not meaningful because it doesn’t represent a string so `datastring` will be `nil`. Use valid data like

```
let chars : [UInt8] = [72, 101, 108, 108, 111]
let datastring = String(bytes: chars, encoding: .utf8) // "Hello"
```

Answer (score 4):

In Swift 3 you can use this:

```
import Foundation
let chars: [UInt8] =  [255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0]
let string = String(data: Data(chars), encoding: .utf8)
```

Comment: Simpler: `String(bytes: chars, encoding: .utf8)`

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for your answer. You should consider adding it on your own.

Comment: Its giving string as nil. Can you tell me why??

Comment: getting nil string. Is there any other solution?

Comment: getting nil string as well.

Answer (score 0):

let str = String(decoding: chars, as: UTF8.self) - changes wrong byts by 0xfffd
let str = chars.map { String(UnicodeScalar($0)) }.joined()