# How to convert byte array to string in swift 3

Tags: arrays, string, swift3, md5, cryptographic-hash-function

I referred C# code for byte array to string conversion in swift

```
System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(encryptedpassword)
```

I tried to convert byte array to string by using below few codes:

(A)

```
 let utf8 : [UInt8] = [231, 13, 38, 246, 234, 144, 148, 111, 174, 136, 15, 61, 200, 186, 215, 113,0]
 let str = NSString(bytes: utf8, length: utf8.count, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
 print("str : \(str)")
```

result : getting nil value

(B)

```
 let datastring = NSString(bytes: chars, length: count, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
 print("string byte data\(chars.map{"\($0)"}.reduce(""){$0+$1})")
```

result : 23113382462341441481111741361561200186215113 (I thought this is not ideal way)

I searched from last two days and tried other multiple ways but I missed something or doing some mistake .
Please help me out resolved this issue.

Referred links:
[how-to-convert-uint8-byte-array-to-string-in-swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29643986/how-to-convert-uint8-byte-array-to-string-in-swift)

[how-to-convert-uint8-byte-array-to-string-in-swift 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35620543/swift-converting-byte-array-into-string)

Comment: That's certainly not a readable UTF8 string? You might first decrypt it.

Comment: You are right UTF8 encoding not readable but in C# they pass byte array encryptedpassword into GetString() with encoding UTF8.Is there any alternate way in swift ?

Comment: As long as the string is not UTF8 compatible you have to deal with raw `Data`. You can convert `[UInt8]` to data simply with `let data = Data(utf8)`

Comment: Means I need to convert by using String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)

Comment: Basically yes, but this will fail with your encrypted string, too

Comment: but how can I pass byte array like [231, 13, 38, 246, 234, 144, 148, 111, 174, 136, 15, 61, 200, 186, 215, 113] to data .

Comment: As I said `Data(utf8)` but you cannot convert the data to String

Comment: when I print Data(utf8) on console then I got  dataString utf8 : 17 bytes

Comment: Yes, that's normal. `print(Data(utf8) as NSData)` shows you the raw bytes.

Comment: Ok. Can I pass this data into String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8). Is it worked?

Comment: No, you can't. Please read my comments carefully. Once again you can't because it's not an UTF8 string.

Comment: You are right .Getting nil value

Comment: then what should I do ? I need to pass String type value to API

Comment: Is there any alternate way?

Comment: You could use another encoding. But could it be that the API expects a **base64** encoded string?

Comment: Data to base64string conversion is possible ?

Comment: Yes, of course: `Data(utf8).base64EncodedString()`

Comment: @vadian I able to convert byte Array to string                                                           let inputl: [UInt8] = [37, 213, 90, 210, 131, 170, 64, 10, 244, 100, 199, 109, 113, 60, 7, 173]                                                                                                                print("datastring8 : \(String(decoding: inputl, as: UTF8.self))")                               output is : datastring8 : %�Z҃�@
�d�mq<�      (macOS result)

Comment: online swift compiler with using both windows and macOS both gives different result . Windows result is:                                                                      
 % Z҃ @
 d mq<                                                                                                                     
 server side changes can't be possible I suggest them to use base64 but no help

Comment: Sorry I can't help because I don't know the specification of the API.

Comment: Actually same code run for byte array to string conversion in swift but when I tried to run by using online compiler with Windows os result is little difference and I also tried with C# code again shows little different output.I want same result in different os .Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi @vadian Thanks for helping me.I really inspire your approach.I resolved this issued by following your steps and implementing according to that                           1.step : decode  byte array to String                                                                                                         2.step : convert string to Data                                                                                  3.step : convert Data to String

Comment: let datar = String(decoding: MD5ByteArray, as: UTF8.self)                                             let datas = Data(datar.utf8)                                                                                               let datarToString = String(data: datas, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!